# How to change a value in onclick function button

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

i will like to change the status of a user in my database from inactive to active by clicking on a button.

i have a function already which show if the use is active or inactive on the database by asigning a value to them eg 0 for inactive and 1 for active.

below is the function that change the value on the button if the user is inactive or active

```
 if ( $row["active"] == 1 ) {
echo '<button class="btn-u btn-u-green" type="button">Active</button>';
  } else {
 echo '<button class="btn-u btn-u-red" type="button">Inactive</button>';
  }
```

now i need to create a function that handle the active and inactive button. like when an admin clicks on inactive (Button) it update the value into the database to 1 (Active), and if the admin click on the active button again it update the value to 0 (inactive),

below is what i have done so far

Button Table bellow

```
<td>                                                                                        
<?php                                                                                                                                                 
  if ( $row["active"] == 1 ) {
echo '<button onclick="button" name="active" class="btn-u btn-green" type="button">Active</button>';
} else {
echo '<button name="inactive" class="btn-u btn-u-red" type="button">Inactive</button>';
 }
?></td>
```

database settings

```
<?php

$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$databasename = "testone";

try
{

$conn = new PDO ("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$databasename",$username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    if(isset($_POST["active"]))
}
    $query = "INSERT INTO users(active) VALUE (:1)";
    $statement = $conn->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute(
        array(
            'users' => $_POST['active']
        )
    );
    $count = $statement->rowCount();
    if($count > 0)
    {
        echo "data insert successfully";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "data insertion failed";
    }
}
}
catch(PODExeption $error)
{

    echo $error->GetMessage(); 
}

?>
```

function i used

```
<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
  <script>

 $(document).raedy(function(){
   $('button[type="button"]').click(function(){
 var active = $(this).val();

  $.ajax({
    url:"activateagent.php",
    method:"POST",
   data:{users:active},
 success: function(data){
 $('$result').html(data);
       }
     });
       });
     });

 </script>
```

in my console i get this error ReferenceError: button is not defined

Thanks

Comment: what have you tried till now , can you please show?

Comment: bad link @AmanjotKaur  that link has SQL injections in it uses the old legacy `mysql_*` functions which are deprecated in short it is pretty much *"trash"*.. ..

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth thats why am here show me how to arrange the code

Comment: @RaymondNijland what link

Comment: *"RaymondNijland what link "* he removed that comment after i posted mine comment it seams @FnepShevoo

Comment: "_show me how to arrange the code_" That's not how this site works. At least show _some_ effort and paste the code you already have along with the errors you get.

Comment: @kerbholz I am really sorry.

Comment: @FnepShevoo bro this is not a freelance website, at least you should try something and then ask for resolution.

Comment: below is what i have do @PrabhjotSinghKainth

Comment: @RaymondNijland i just added my code

Answer (score 0):

There are so many errors in the code, make following changes:

```
<td>                                                                                        
<?php                                                                                                                                                 
  if ( $row["active"] == 1 ) {
echo '<button class="btn-u btn-green btn_send" id="<?php echo $row["active"];?>">Active</button>';
} else {
echo '<button class="btn-u btn-u-red btn_send" id="<?php echo $row["active"];?>">Inactive</button>';
 }
?></td>
```

Now in JQuery code make these changes:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('.btn_send').on('click',function(){
 var active = $(this).attr('id');

  $.ajax({
    url:"activateagent.php",
    method:"POST",
   data:{users:active},
 success: function(data){
 $('$result').html(data);
       }
     });
       });
     });
```